# Is a comma the correct punctuation in "Help a thief?"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Recently, one of my friends on Facebook posted [this cartoon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqDbX.jpg) in which a police officer helps a thief in response to the exclamation "Help a thief!" The contention is that the victim should have used a comma. However, in my eyes, a comma does not seem appropriate. Rather, I would expect an exclamation point, period, or colon.

Is a comma correct for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A comma is often used to set an exclamation apart from the remainder of the sentence.

> Boy, that really hurt.

You are correct in offering an exclamation point and period as alternatives. The former would emphasize the tone. The latter would be correct, but a bit understated.

A colon does not make much sense. The material following a colon is generally definitional of the material preceding. It might work of your statement were

> Danger: a thief!

Logical, but somewhat pedantic.

The cartoon is reminiscent of the popular book discussing grammar, *[Eats, Shoots & Leaves](http://www.lynnetruss.com/pages/content/?PageID=8)*.